# Flutter Multiple texts inside a Container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Wanted to know how could i achieve this inside a Container [image]

```
return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: width,
                          height: height / 3,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 3,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: Container have a child so use Column in side in Container

Comment: im just having a problem having the text on the left and at the right like its is on the picture, when i made the column i would do cross axis alignment to start, than im struggling making the text on the right at the right part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

[image]

```
Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 3,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text("a"),
                Spacer(flex: 1,),
                Text("B")
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text("a"),
                Spacer(flex: 1,),
                Text("B")
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text("a"),
                Spacer(flex: 1,),
                Text("B")
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
```

**OR**

```
Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 3,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(

        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("a"),
              
                Text("B")
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("a"),
             
                Text("B")
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("a"),
              
                Text("B")
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
```

**parameters set your according**

**Two Way**

Answer (score 1):

Check Solution below its help you.

```
 Column(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
 children:[
 Row(children:[
 Text("Name"),Spacer(),Text("Abc")
 ]),
 Row(children:[
 Text("class"),Spacer(),Text("2nd")
 ])
 ])
```